# Can someone set me straight on SSH into my personal computer?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I have opened port 22 on my router (using the Belkin GUI) and it forwards to the ip of my computer (the one that is 192.xxx..x.x) and I have sshd listening on port 22.  I can ssh in from within my wifi network, but cannot do it from outside.  Am I missing something?

Comment: How are you SSH-ing to your computer? Did you try to ssh to your external IP address? (ie the WAN IP, not the computer internal IP)

Comment: How would I find that?

Comment: Try opening whatismyip.com or go into your router status and it should display what is your current external IP is. then try to ssh to that. If your router is working as it should, the router will receive the SSH request on port 22 (at its external IP), and then it will forward the request to your computer (192.xxx.x.x) and your computer will handle the ssh transaction.

Comment: It's still timing out.  Does the computer I'm trying to connect to need to be connected to the router via ethernet or is wifi ok?

Comment: The computer you need to connect can be on ethernet and can be on wireless, that is not the issue. So assuming your external IP is 10.0.0.1, and your internal IP is 192.168.1.2 (and you set your router to forward port 22 to 192.168.1.2) when you SSH to 10.0.0.1 on port 22, it is still timing out?

Comment: yes it is still timing out

Comment: How have you verified that the port forwarding is actually working? Also have you checked your firewall rules on the host in question to make sure it isn't filtering out ssh connections from external IP addresses?

Comment: How can I verify those? Actually it looks like it is closed.  The router GUI is not the most intuitive.  It has two input fields for each port number.

Answer (score 0):

It works!  Fun fact, there is an "on" radio button that needs to be clicked.
If you have a Belkin router: Make the description "Active" check the "on" box and for both boxes in both inbound port and private port, write the port twice (eg 22-22 22-22).

Comment: @neersighted: AFAIK, one cannot accept their own answer for the first 24 hours since it (or the question?) was posted...

Comment: That's true I can't.